# Inserting into production table from the latest archive table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a project where I need to insert into a production table the data that is in an archive table. The problem is that I have multiple archive tables for a specific table, all with a timestamp at the end of the table name. My idea was to find the latest archive table by doing this:

`select top (1) table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where TABLE_CATALOG = 'databasename' and table_name like 'archive_User_%'  order by table_name desc`

This will give me the name of the last archive table for "User".
Question is, how to I write my insert into query to use this as the name of the table I want to insert into from?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

> how to I write my insert into query to use this as the name of the table I want to insert into from?

Dynamic SQL.  EG:

```
declare @tn sysname 
declare @schema sysname

select top (1) @tn = name , @schema = schema_name(schema_id)
from sys.tables 
where  name like 'archive_User_%'  
order by name desc


declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat( '
insert into sometable (a,b,c,d)
select a,b,c,d
from ',quotename(@schema),'.',quotename(@tn),';
')

--print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @QueryText nVarChar(max)

Select @QueryText = Concat('Insert Into ', QuoteName(s.name), '.', QuoteName(t.name), ' (', 
STRING_AGG(c.name,', '), ')', Char(10), 'Select ', STRING_AGG(c.name,', '), 
Char(10),'From ', QuoteName(t1.schemaName), '.', QuoteName(t1.tableName))
From sys.tables as t Inner Join sys.schemas as s On (t.schema_id=s.schema_id)
                     Inner Join sys.columns as c On (t.object_id=c.object_id)
                    ,(Select Max(name) As tableName, schema_name(schema_id) as 
                     schemaName From sys.tables Where name Like 'archive_User_%' 
                     And schema_name(schema_id)='SchemaName' Group by 
                     schema_name(schema_id)) As t1
Where t.name = 'TableName'
      And s.name = 'SchemaName'
   -- And c.name Not In ('ColumnName1','ColumnName2')
Group by s.name, t.name, t1.tableName, t1.schemaName

Execute sp_executesql @QueryText
```